# ACF field text have Blocks after the it is rendered

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am having an issue while using the_field element from ACF. When the fields are echoed, there are squares added after the text on Windows 10 machines but the fun part is that I tried the site on a different computer with Windows 10 and Chrome and it rendered without any issues. All the fields are manually entered so encoding shouldn't have any effect on it.

```
<h1 class="bfold_h1"><?php the_field('home_above_title'); ?></h1>
```

This is how it's on the back end
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zja6tvxv9y8z3y9/Screenshot%202017-02-07%2012.39.57.png?dl=0

This is how it's rendered on Chrome in OS X
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvfnuwvqb2uhm8t/Screenshot%202017-02-07%2012.40.48.png?dl=0

and this is how it's rendered on Windows Chrome
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bl4182ja339dyxc/Screenshot%202017-02-07%2012.43.18.png?dl=0

Any ideas appreciated, I checked phpmyadmin and the fields don't have any hidden characters. The field is simple text field.

Comment: do you face the same problem with `echo get_field(home_above_title)`

Comment: Yes I just updated just to try, same result, the text is rendered, and then in Chrome there is a box after the text. Just Confirmed that's happening in Chrome in Windows.

Comment: Was the text copied from Photoshop? We've been experiencing this same thing recently. There are some hidden characters, usually line breaks, that have been showing up in text copied from Photoshop. For about 3 months it's been showing up in the beta version of Chrome, but apparently whatever was doing this made it into the live version recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been experiencing this same issue when copying text from Adobe Photoshop, and pasting it into custom fields. They only render in the Chrome browser. They appear to be some hidden characters signifying things like line breaks inside Photoshop.

In order to remove them, I've been selecting all the text in a field, pasting it into a text editor, then copying from the text editor and pasting back into the custom field.

There may be other ways to solve this, but this is what's been working for me.

These characters used to only appear in a beta version of Chrome, but in the last week or two, these changes made it into the Live version.

Comment: I run a validator on Coda and found U-003 breaks so it was something similar for sure. I removed all breaks and everything was updated.